# Ruby input doesnt works (newbie)

Tags: ruby, linux, input

the problem occurs when I put the inputs (n1, n2) and the console still request me for more inputs.

my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def Euclides(n1,n2)
    while n1 % n2 != 0
        aux = n1
        n1 = n2
        n2 = aux % n2
    end
    return n2
end

n1 = gets
n2 = gets
puts Euclides(n1,n2)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The problem is not with `gets`, I just tested. Your code is falling infinite loop, thus it seems to you. Just put `puts 123` before the loop, you can see that, control goes there.

Comment: not is infty loop, try with 2 values in function, like this:
puts Euclides(5,10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that what you get from `gets` is a string. Passing two strings to your method results in an infinite loop since `string1 % string2` will always return `string1` (unless you have some special syntax in that string, see [`%`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-25) documentation for string.

To solve you problem, you should convert your strings to integers:

```
n1 = gets.to_i
n2 = gets.to_i
puts Euclides(n1,n2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to place inputs side by side. Like:

```
n1, n2
```

Try

```
n1, n2 = gets.split(/,/).map(&:rstrip)
```

Comment: Yes, I also have the same in my mind. But still thinking the issue OP told. I don't have still any answer for the same.